# How can I add libraries to a project in a system independent way?

Tags: c++, qt, libraries, environment

I'm developing an application using Qt and OpenGL, and found it necessary to download the GLM library. It's a header-only library, so I don't need to link to anything. I want this application to build on any system that has the correct libraries installed. My problem is that I don't know where to put GLM so that the system can find it without adding a specific path to the project's .pro file. The .pro file is part of my git repository, which is how the source is distributed to other systems like Linux, etc. So I don't want this file to specify the exact location of GLM because other systems could have it in other places.

I'm currently developing on Windows, compiling in Qt Creator using Visual C++ 2010. I read from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28VS.80%29.aspx) that `#include <file>` searches using the INCLUDE environment variable, so I tried to add the path to glm.hpp to INCLUDE, but QtCreator's build environment for this project seems to overwrite INCLUDE. So I appended the path to GLM to the new INCLUDE from within QtCreator's Projects tab, but my code still can't find glm.hpp.

In general, how can I add an external library to my system such that my compiler will be able to find it without specifying the exact location in a project file that's distributed to other systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a build system with the power to search the system for the libraries you request, and be able to do so on any platform. One such build system is [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/), and it is the most widely used build system. In essence, cmake allows you to write a build script in which you can specify all the things you normally specify when creating a project in Qt Creator or Visual Studio, like the list of source files, grouped by targets to compile (libraries, executables, etc.), the relative paths to the headers, and libraries to include for linking and for include-paths, amongst many more things. For libraries that are installed on the system, there is a function, called [`find_package()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_package) (part of cmake script commands), that will find out if the library is installed and where to find its lib files and headers (storing those paths as cache strings that you can specify on the targets and such). It usually works great, as long as the libraries are not installed in weird places. The way it works is that when you run cmake, it will generate a build script/configuration for almost any platform you specify, and then you use that to compile your code. It can generate makefiles (Unix-like or windows), CodeBlocks project files, Visual Studio project files, etc.. And many IDEs also have native support for cmake projects.

I wish I could recommend an alternative, just to sound less biased for cmake, but I haven't heard of any that truly compare to it, especially for the purpose of locating external dependencies and working with different platforms. I would guess [Boost.Build](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/) is decent too.